# update data in sub document without overwrite another field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

data in database

```
fieldA : 'aaaaa',
fieldB : {
      en : 'aaaaaaaaaa',
      de : 'bbbbbbbbbb'
}
```

new data

```
val = {
fieldA : 'aaaaa11',
fieldB : {
            en : 'aaaaa1111'
         }
}
```

i tried this code

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({fieldA : val.fieldA},{ $set : val})
```

when i run this command 'fieldB.de' is missing. i want to know how to update as result seem below

```
fieldA : 'aaaaa11',
fieldB : {
  en : 'aaaaa1111',
  de : 'bbbbbbbbbb'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the object passed to `findOneAndUpdate()` so that you don't pass `fieldB` as an object, only the fields to update.
It can be done with something like this:

```
let val = {
  fieldA: 'aaaaa11',
  fieldB: {
    en: 'aaaaa1111',
  },
};

if (val.fieldB) {
  const newFieldB = Object.entries(val.fieldB).reduce(
    (a, [key, value]) => ({ ...a, ['fieldB.' + key]: value }),
    {}
  );
  delete val.fieldB;
  val = { ...val, ...newFieldB };
}

Model.findOneAndUpdate({fieldA : val.fieldA},{ $set : val})
```

With that, the value of `val` passed to `findOneAndUpdate()` is:

```
{
  fieldA: 'aaaaa11',
  'fieldB.en': 'aaaaa1111',
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
  fieldA: 'aaaaa11',
  fieldB: {
    en: 'aaaaa1111',
  },
}
```

... and attributes of `fieldB` that you didn't specify in `val` but that were in your DB will not get overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({fieldA : val.fieldA},{
  "$set": {
    "fieldA": val.fieldA,
    "fieldB.en": val.fieldB.en
  }
})
```

In your solution you update document completny with other one. To update only specific fields you must specify this fields in "$set" object

Comment: It work. But i have a many object (fieldA....fieldZ). If i use this solution my code is very long

Comment: Model.findOne().then(obj => {
Object.assign(obj, updatedObj);
obj.save()
}

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this by finding the document first and editing de object manually.

```js
/* Recursive function to update manually an object */
const update = (obj, newValues) => {
  Object.entries(newValues).forEach( ([key, value]) => {
    if(typeof value === 'object'){
      update(obj[key], value);
    } else {
      obj[key] = value;
    }
  });
}
/* Find document, update and save */
const infoToUpdate = {};
const doc = await Model.findOne({ field: valueToFind });
if (doc) {
  object.update(doc, infoToUpdate);
  doc.save();
}
```